# Triggering Sparkle updates in all apps?

Tags: applications

I've been annoyed and concerned with Macupdate's recent inclusion of adware in some of their update packages.

I realize that a lot of apps that aren't from the Mac App Store include the Sparkle updater functionality, but it requires launching the app to trigger the update check.

Is there a way to scan for all apps with the Sparkle updater and trigger the update check one by one?

Edit: I just discovered [this post at SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380546/calling-sparkle-updater-from-outside-the-application). Perhaps it's too convoluted a process.

Comment: Found this project in a forum post about the same question: https://github.com/kolpanic/Coruscation. `A utility that checks all installed Sparkle-enabled macOS apps for updates`. Haven't tried it in HighSierra though.

Comment: Thanks, nathan. That's exactly what I was looking for. I may try it if I'm feeling brave.